# Visual Studio 2010 Keyboard Shortcut Chords

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I started out with VB6 default shortcuts where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> brings up the Solution Explorer window.

Now when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> I see a status message saying that VS is waiting for me to hit the next sequence in the chord, suggesting to me that I have shortcuts that begin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> but require another keystroke.

This suggests to me that having one or more shortcut sequences that begin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>invalidates the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut, which I can understand, but the question is, how do I find what those command are so I can assign a different sequence to them?

Also, shouldn't VS warn me when assigning the first chord shorcut that begins with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> that this will invalidate my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut or, it should clear it out so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is no longer a shortcut for the Solution Explorer window.

Anyway, I guess the question is how do I locate the commands that begin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> so I can change them so they dont collide with my Solution Explorer shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2010, `Tools` | `Options` | `Environment` | `Keyboard` gets you to the right place. Now, put the cursor in `Press shortcut keys`, and press the keys you are interested in (so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). The `Shortcut currently used by` dropdown will then show you all the shortcuts that currently involve the keys you have pressed.

I agree it would be a 'nice to have' for VS to warn about overlapping shortcuts, but note that different shortcuts can have different scopes of effect (in the `Use new shortcut in` dropdown), so this might not be as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 4):

The [keybindings poster from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f&displaylang=en) might be helpful. It looks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> behaves differently depending on if you are debugging or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IntelliCommand Plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/83f59659-abc1-4bfa-9779-42f687af0481). This helped me out a lot in learning and remembering the chrod combinations.

Also [Learn the shortcut Plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/29f07f2c-68aa-47fa-b1c3-48065209b110) is pretty cool too.